# How to access JSON data in another html page?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, httprequest

I am trying get request to fake `jsonplaceholder api` site. Also, I got the result and list placeholder/todos datas as its title on my HTML page. I want to click selected todo item and it will redirect another html page to list item details as id,userId,title,completed properties. But, I can redirect only id property, I can't redirect other properties.

```
            success: function (e) {
                let items=e;
                for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

               //console.log(jsonitem[i]);
                 $('#todos').append('<a class="todo-item" onclick="onItemClick(' +items[i].title
                         + ')">' + items[i].title + '</a>')
                         console.log(items[i]);

                }

            },
    function onItemClick(jsonitem){
        window.document.location='./index3.html'+'?item='+jsonitem;
    }
```

//another html page

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      let items = document.location.search.replace(/^.*?\=/,'');

      $("#txtDetail").html(items);
      console.log(items);
    })
```

Comment: In a nutshell, you cannot! If both pages were open in different frames in the browser then you could access them, but think of the life cycle.  A page and the data on it only exists while it is open, once its closed the data is gone!

Comment: but it is possible to list their id's another page. problem is I cant list another properties.

Comment: Maybe you need to `encodeURIComponent(jsonitem)` when constructing the query string.

Comment: console.log(items[i]) lists and shows all items as {userId: 10, id: 185, title: "voluptates dignissimos sed doloribus animi quaerat aut", completed: false}, this is okay but onItemClick( items[i] ) method gives me onItemClick(Object object) error, what is problem ??